# git history of a function with overloading

Tags: git, function, methods, overloading

With git show a function history, I can use `git -L :functionName:fileName`.

But for something language such as C++, function overload allow more than one function with same funcation name, like,

```
int sum(int a,int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

double sum(double a,double b)
{
    return a+b;
}
float sum(float a,float b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

How to show the one specific function history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [git doc](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Lltstartgtltendgtltfilegt)

> -L ,:
>   -L ::
>   ....
>
> If `“:<funcname>”` is given in place of  and , it is a
>   regular expression that denotes the range from the first funcname line
>   that matches `<funcname>`, up to the next funcname line. `“:<funcname>”`
>   searches from the end of the previous -L range, if any, otherwise from
>   the start of file. `“^:<funcname>”` searches from the start of file.

`:function` is a regular expression, it will match function with pattern `function` and track it's history.

So to track specific function, just modify the pattern to make it more clear.

For example to track `double sum(double a,double b)` just use `git log -L :sum\(double:filepath`.